# Generic method that accepts both { [key: string]: V } and { [key: number]: V } mappings

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to write a utility method that searches any map and I want to enforce that the key type matches the predicate type.

How would the appropriate method signature looks like, if there is any?

E.g I would like to generalize this signature:

```js
someKey<V>(object: { [key: string]: V }, predicate: (key: string) => boolean): boolean {
   // ....
}
```

I have tried this, but it gives me a compiler error (probably because "extends"), though **it best describes what I am thinking of**:

```js
someKey<K extends string|number, V>(object: { [key: K]: V }, predicate: (key: K) => boolean): boolean {
   // ....
}
```

The following allows for both types of maps, but not fully. I.e. it allows that the predicate sports methods (like key.startsWith(..)) that are not present on numbers, but work because of automatic type conversion, but it forbids the use of numerical operators like > or < for numerical keys:

```js
someKey<V>(object: { [key: string]: V }|{ [key: number]: V }, predicate: (key: string) => boolean): boolean {
   // ....
}
```

The following allows for both types of maps, but forbids using methods like string.startsWith(..), though it allows for mathematical operators like > and < (which doesn't make sense in a way), also if it would work, it lacks enforcing that the key type matches the predicate type.

```js
someKey<V>(object: { [key: string]: V }|{ [key: number]: V }, predicate: (key: string|number) => boolean): boolean {
   // ....
}
```

---

Edit:
The suggested solution:

```js
someKey<K extends string|number, V>(object: { [key in keyof K]: V }, predicate: (key: K) => boolean): boolean {
   return true; // your actual logic
}
```

Raises a compile error (click to magnify) on the using end:
[image: compile error with suggested solution]
Using Typescript 2.7.2

---

Edit: 
Also tried this:

```js
someKey<M extends { [key: string]: any } | { [key: number]: any }>
       (object: M, predicate: (key: keyof M) => boolean): boolean {
  return true; // body goes here
}
```

but then if I do:

```js
const testMap2 = {
    1: 'a',
    2: 'bb',
    3: 'ccc',
    4: 'dddd',
    5: 'eeeee',
  };

  it('#someKey should return true if found', () => {
    expect(Utility.someKey(testMap2, key => key > 1)).toBe(true);
  });
```

it says:

```
(parameter) key: "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5"
Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.ts(2365)
```

---

Edit:

There were Issues filed against Typescript:

- [The generics don't work with the type of a key value object #16957](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16957)
- [Cannot use valid union type as a map's key](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27219)

Looks like there is an open Pull request for typescript 3.x:

- [Allow any key type as an index signature parameter type #26797](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797)

Still a workaround for this issue is appreciated, if there exist one.

Comment: Hey, I just test out your last attempt in TS 3.4, it works fine. And it does infer number-type key from generic type param correctly. You've got the solution right, just TS 2.x doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks for testing!

Answer (score 0):

Should look like this

```
function someKey<K extends string|number, V>(object: { [key in keyof K]: V }, predicate: (key: K) => boolean): boolean {
    return true; // your actual logic
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work:

    const testMap = {
        'a': 1,
        'bb': 2,
        'ccc': 3,
        'dddd': 4,
        'eeeee': 5,
     };

     it('#someKey should return true if found', () => {
        expect(Utility.someKey(testMap, key => key.startsWith('c'))).toBe(true);
     });

"Argument of type '{ 'a': number; 'bb': number; 'ccc': number; 'dddd': number; 'eeeee': number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
  Type '{ 'a': number; 'bb': number; 'ccc': number; 'dddd': number; 'eeeee': number; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts"

Comment: @Brixomatic It is unreadable, but you have to implement your function body yourself. I provided the function signature only.

Comment: Tried to correct the formatting, but doesn't work for me in comments.
Using the signature, even with an empty body prompts a compiler error at the user side.

Comment: @Brixomatic The error is because there is an empty function body which returns nothing. It has nothing to do with the function signature.

Comment: Nope. I can just return "undefined" as function body. 
Using typescript 2.7.2, maybe it's the TS version.